# Does oibaf's drivers works with ati mobility radeon x1400 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Im triyng to improve my gpu performance, and Ive read that this are good drivers but i cant find a list with the supported hardware and I dont want to ruin my ubuntu 16.04 by installing this drivers, nor getting the annoying black screen to be solved with terminal commands. By the way Im using the open Radeon driver.

Another thing, if I install this drivers and I want to get rid of them, using ppa purge is going to be enough?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are no drivers that can improve the performance of such obsolete card.

Comment: Ok, but for testing purposes could they be installed with this gpu without inconveniences?

Comment: Currently there are no proprietary drivers compatible with newer kernels/Xorg. The one you're running is the only one currently available. Try anything else and may end up with a broken system.

Comment: Oh, I see... Well thank you for your response, you saved me big time.